# Cookies are not accessible from sub directories

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

Suppose I have the domain **www.example.com** and in the page **test_cookie.php** I've written this piece of code:

```
setcookie("cookie","test",time()+3600*5,"/");
```

Setting the path parameter to "/" to make it accessible for all paths.
What is weird is that when I try to access it from a sub directory such as **administration**, I cannot. I've tested this peice of code under **www.example.com/administration/test_cookie.php**:

```
echo $_COOKIE['cookie'];
```

It is ever more weird when I tried this code under **www.example.com/test_cookie.php**

```
setcookie("cookie","test",time()+3600*5,"/administration");
```

And again, I couldn't access it from the sub directory.

The **phpinfo();** is available [here](http://taksa-agri.com/administration/test_cookie.php) in case you need information about the php installed on the server.

PS: At the same time, the variable is accessible under **www.example.com/test_cookie.php**

Comment: As far as I'm concerned yo don't need to add the "/" parameter. I always use `setcookie('cookie','value',time()+3600*5);` and it works in all the subdomains as well.
Also, it's not advised to put your `phpinfo()` file available for everyone. Like this, they can see what version/setup you have and can more easily exploit bugs or so.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code , there's something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: @arbitter I tested this too, same result.